# In R why does a factor resulting from interaction() have a different length of levels vs length of unique values

Tags: r

There is something special about `interaction()` that I am missing. For example if you have a dataset that looks like,

```
t<- c(rep("a", 10), rep("b", 10), rep("c", 10))
r<- c(rep("1", 5), rep("2", 5), rep("3", 5), rep("4", 5), rep("5", 5), rep("6", 5))
test<- data.frame(t,r)
```

and then you get the interaction between `t` and `r`

```
test$Interaction <- with(test, interaction(t, r))
```

You get a factor

```
class(test$Interaction)
```

Yet now you have three times the number of levels than unique values

```
length(unique(test$Interaction))
length(levels(test$Interaction))
```

I am missing something because `?interaction` does explain why this is. Anyway, I am just curious about what's going on (and why the interaction is not stored as a list). Thanks for light you could shed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default `interaction()` will create a level for all possible combinations of values between the two input vectors, even if those observations don't actually occur. For example it created a level for `b.1` even though that did not occur in your data.

```
table( with(test, interaction(t, r)) )
# a.1 b.1 c.1 a.2 b.2 c.2 a.3 b.3 c.3 a.4 b.4 c.4 
#   5   0   0   5   0   0   0   5   0   0   5   0 
# a.5 b.5 c.5 a.6 b.6 c.6 
#   0   0   5   0   0   5
```

You can change that behavior by using `drop=TRUE` when calling `interaction()`

```
test$Interaction <- with(test, interaction(t, r, drop=TRUE))
length(unique(test$Interaction))
# [1] 6
length(levels(test$Interaction))
# [1] 6
```

Comment: Ooohhhh... Yeah that makes sense. I suppose if I am doing a later meta-analysis I would want to keep those levels? In any case, thank you so much for this answer.